# Most Efficient Way To Run A Query On PROCEDURE Results

Tags: php, mysql, performance, stored-procedures, procedure

*Any help is appreciated.*

I am trying to create a query on the results generated from a MySQL **PROCEDURE**. Prefereably, I would like to modify this **PROCEDURE** to be a **JOIN** and do this all in 1 query, but from what I have been reading this is not possible, so I am looking for the most efficient way to query information from the same database but different tables, linked by the ID of the destination.

***eg: query the address table and grab each address of each result of the PROCEDURE linked by the ID***

Is there any way to avoid doing 50 extra queries, if the PROCEDURE returns 50 different "destinations" or results? I am assuming the most effective way to do this is to create another procedure.

**PROCEDURE Code - This procedure queries the database and grabs points based on latitude and longitude. The data is provided by MAXMIND and can be found here:**

https://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GEODIST`( IN userid int, IN dist int, IN olat float, IN olon float ) DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA

BEGIN
DECLARE mylon DOUBLE;
DECLARE mylat DOUBLE;
DECLARE lon1 FLOAT;
DECLARE lon2 FLOAT;
DECLARE lat1 FLOAT;
DECLARE lat2 FLOAT;

SET mylon = olon;
SET mylat = olat;
SET lon1 = mylon - dist / abs( cos( radians( mylat ) ) * 69 );
SET lon2 = mylon + dist / abs( cos( radians( mylat ) ) * 69 );
SET lat1 = mylat - ( dist / 69 );
SET lat2 = mylat + ( dist / 69 );

SELECT destination.id, destination.latitude, destination.longitude, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((origin.latitude -destination.latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(origin.latitude * pi()/180) * COS(destination.latitude * pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((origin.longitude -destination.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance FROM locations destination, locations origin WHERE origin.id = userid
AND destination.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 AND destination.latitude BETWEEN lat1 and lat2 
HAVING distance < dist ORDER BY distance LIMIT 50;
END
```

Call to the procedure:

```
CALL GEODIST( $userid, $distance, $latitude, $longitude )
```

***EDIT***

Currently, I have edited the code using the suggestions from the comments section, but I have received an error still trying to create the PROCEDURE. I tried to use an alias for both the destination and in this case photos table but it throws the error:

***Error:***

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd, locations origin JOIN photos p ON d.id = p.lid WHERE origin.id = userid AND ' at line 18


CREATE PROCEDURE `GEODIST`( IN userid int, IN dist int, IN olat float, IN olon float ) DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA

BEGIN
DECLARE mylon DOUBLE;
DECLARE mylat DOUBLE;
DECLARE lon1 FLOAT;
DECLARE lon2 FLOAT;
DECLARE lat1 FLOAT;
DECLARE lat2 FLOAT;

SET mylon = olon;
SET mylat = olat;
SET lon1 = mylon - dist / abs( cos( radians( mylat ) ) * 69 );
SET lon2 = mylon + dist / abs( cos( radians( mylat ) ) * 69 );
SET lat1 = mylat - ( dist / 69 );
SET lat2 = mylat + ( dist / 69 );

SELECT d.id, d.name, d.address, d.latitude, d.longitude, d.category, d.type, p.lid, p.pid, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((origin.latitude -d.latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(origin.latitude * pi()/180) * COS(d.latitude * pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((origin.longitude -d.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance FROM locations d, locations origin JOIN photos p ON d.id = p.lid WHERE origin.id = userid
AND d.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 AND d.latitude BETWEEN lat1 and lat2 
HAVING distance < dist ORDER BY distance LIMIT 50;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly can't you just left join the address table?

```
SELECT destination.id, destination.latitude, destination.longitude, 
3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((origin.latitude -destination.latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(origin.latitude * pi()/180) * COS(destination.latitude * pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((origin.longitude -destination.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
AS distance 
FROM 
locations destination, 
locations origin,
LEFT JOIN
addressTable
ON addressTable.id = destination.id
WHERE 
origin.id = userid
AND destination.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 
AND destination.latitude BETWEEN lat1 and lat2
HAVING distance < dist 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 50;
```

It's hard to test without the data but I believe it is something like that.

**EDIT FOR AUTHORS EDIT**

In your new code you replace the following:

```
FROM locations d, locations origin 
JOIN photos p ON d.id = p.lid
```

with the appropriate names of the tables you are pulling from it should be something like this:

```
FROM destination d, origin o,
JOIN photos p
ON d.id = p.lid
```

When we use aliases we are simply saying select some stuff from table "destination" but lets nick name it "d" so we don't have a really long sql statement.

Also, in the select you want do use the same aliases that where used in the FROM clause.  For example:

```
SELECT destination.id, destination.latitude
```

should be

```
SELECT d.id, d.latitude
```

Comment: From what I have been reading you can't use a join in a MYSQL Procedure, but I will try this, I was trying to add a JOIN, but MySQL kept throwing an error trying to insert the JOIN in the code, I'll try really quick and get back to you. Thanks I really appreciate any help!

Comment: How is the query specifying what to query for on the address table?

Comment: You must add that on the SELECT statement.  So it would be yourAddressTableName.columnName in the select portion of the sql.  It might be helpful to use aliases here to avoid confusion.  For example FROM locations destination d, locations origin o, LEFT JOIN locations addressTable a.  Thus, allowing you to use the dot syntax elsewhere.  For example it would be d.id instead of destination.id

Comment: It did not throw an error when putting the JOIN in the procedure this time, ( I guess it was the placement of the JOIN code ), but trying to run the query it returns: #1054 - Unknown column 'destination.id' in 'on clause', I have never had an issue with the query before, I am not exactly sure what this error means, besides it is looking for a destination.id column in the address table?

Comment: Let me try this, Thanks for the input and the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, I just put anything for the on clause because I don't know your data.  So for the on clause you need to say something like the DESTINATION ID that you are selecting is = to the id in the address table.  If this helps mark it as answered or up vote it.  Thanks!

Comment: I thought that was what the destination and the origin was, both aliases for the location table. When I try to change the select statement to using d.id, d.latitude, d.longitude instead of using d.destination, and I add the d to the end of locations destination, and the o to locations origin, I get the error:     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd, locations origin JOIN photos p ON d.id = p.lid WHERE origin.id = userid AND ' at line 18

Comment: I'll do an edit to show the most recent edit I have tried displaying the error I just provided. Thanks for the help again I really appreciate the input from both of you.

Comment: check my edit.  Also if you can make another edit and provide your exact table names I cant try to help further.

Comment: Right, I understand that, when modifying the query, and then calling the PROCEDURE it returns the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'd.id' in 'on clause', and I am not exactly sure what the error is referring to. You know better than I, can you see what is happening? The code I am actually trying to use is in the edit of the original question. Table names are all correct. Thanks again for sticking this out!

Comment: It is like MySQL is not sure all of the sudden what the query is talking about when trying to compare for the JOIN. I believe the issue is happening at the line where the JOIN is and I ask it to JOIN ON d.id = p.id. All the sudden it does not know what d.id is, but it has no problem SELECTING d.id